# dynamic Query in @Query annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, querydsl, specifications, jparepository

I have situation in which I have to compose a JPQL query in some method, then pass this query to spring data query method to be used as the query in @Query annotation.

```java
@Query(value = ":DyanamicQuery")
List<PrizeInsuranceConfiguration> filterConfigurPrizeInsurance(String DyanamicQuery);
```

This is not possible. As it throws compile error. Can you give me an alternat way to achieve this?

```
@Query(value = ":DyanamicQuery")
List<PrizeInsuranceConfiguration> filterConfigurPrizeInsurance(String DyanamicQuery);
```

expected to get Query that I made will go and sit at `value = ":DyanamicQuery"` I also tried giving `@Query("#{#entityName}")`.

Comment: You could use Criteria queries or JPA Specifications or Querydsl.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JPQL query as a string, but you cannot pass it as a parameter to the value attribute of the @Query annotation.

You can use below example -

```
String dyanamicQuery= "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE condition= :condition";

@Query(value = dyanamicQuery)
List<Entity> findByField(@Param("condition") String condition);
```

Or you can use below example also -

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE condition= :condition")
List filterConfigurPrizeInsuranceByField(@Param("condition") String condition);
```

Comment: Can you provide alternative process to achieve this scenario.